# How to install Ionic framework in Ubuntu 18.04 properly with all its dependencies?

Tags: 18.04

I want to know how to install the Ionic framework in Ubuntu 18.04 with all its required dependencies. I tried installing Ionic framework several times but when I run the command 'ionic serve' in the terminal, it gives an error message as '[wdm] failed to compile'. Hence I want the proper steps to install the Ionic framework properly in Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a terminal you can do the following :

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt install -y gcc g++ make nodejs
curl -sL https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y yarn
sudo yarn global add ionic cordova
```

from there you should be operational :

```
ionic start myApp tabs
```

(installing with yarn as opposed to npm is optional but overall you're better off with yarn, here's a yarn cheat sheet : https://shift.infinite.red/npm-vs-yarn-cheat-sheet-8755b092e5cc)

(make sure to first remove everything you already installed with

```
sudo apt purge nodejs -y && sudo apt autoremove -y && sudo apt autoclean
```

and whatever other packages you find appropriate)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the Ionic framework is working fine now!